# Map Tile server for backend Java PDF renderer

Tags: tiles, java, server

We have a Java Application deployed on Tomcat.  There is a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension enabled.  We have both geometries and geo-points in the database.

We have a backend thread that generates PDF reports asynchronously (when requested).  We now want to add maps to the PDFs (based on the geometries) with geo-points plotted.

How can we get access to the necessary map tiles for the PDF from Java?  There is always Internet access from Tomcat, but, obviously, no browser or JavaScript interpreter available.

**Added**
We have found something that suggests installing our own OSM Map Tile Server and using that.  Are there any other options that do not require us to install our own Map Tile Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use any WMS server to read the database and render a map as an image that you can include in your PDF generator. I would recommend [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) since it is easy to set up and will run in your existing tomcat service.

Alternatively, you could create a custom Java program using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) which is the library that GeoServer is built with. It gives you easy access to the [PostGIS database](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) and a [renderer](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/render/index.html) which can draw to a Graphics2D object if that is available in your PDF package.

**Update**

GeoTools has a [TileClient module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/tile-client/tileclient.html) that can read and render OSM & Bing tiles from remote servers. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: When you say "read the database" are you assuming that we have installed a local Map Tile Server (e.g. GeoServer with OSM data)?  I am curious if there are other options without us having to install our own Map Tile Server?  I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: No, in both cases I'm assuming that you only want to draw your own data from PostGIS. You could add any data you liked to GeoServer

Comment: Sorry - I am confused.  In our database all we have are some geometries.  What we need is the maps associated with those geometries so that we can show the geometry on a actual map in the PDF.  From your answer I am not sure from which server we get the map tiles.

Comment: In the first case, you would need to add base mapping to GeoServer. In the second you could import tiles from any public service using the TiledClient

Comment: Sorry - let me clarify again. The desire is that we use an external Map Tile Server like Google, Mapbox, Bing Maps, OSM, etc.  Is there a Java library that would enable that?

Comment: see update ....

Comment: Thank you for all your help and patience in answering my questions (when I was not even sure how to phrase the initial question.)

Comment: Back to the drawing Board: My project is stuck on Java 7.  This means GeoTools v14.5 at the latest.  It looks like GeoTools TileClient was only introduced in a version after that (but I have not been able to tell definitively).  Do you have any other suggestions?